# Show that $f_{n}=nx(1-x^2)^n$ on $[0,1]$ converges point-wise:

Tags: real-analysis

$f_{n}=nx(1-x^2)^n$ on $[0,1]$

what i did

$f_{n}(0)=n(0)(1-0^2)^n=0$

$f_{n}(1)=n(1)(1-1^2)^n=0$

$\therefore f_{n}(0)=f_{n}(1)=0$

$\{f_n\}$ converges point-wise to zero

Is my answer correct?

Comment: It is correct so far. you are not done yet since apparently you haven't dealt yet with the case when $x \neq 0,1$.

Answer (score 2):

For $x\neq 0,1$ we have $\frac{f_{n+1}\ (x)}{f_n(x)}=\frac{(n+1)x(1-x^{2})^{n+1}}{(n)x(1-x^{2})^{n}}$ which tends to $(1-x^{2})$, a number between $0$ and $1.$ Now you can say that it is convergent to zero on $[0,1].$